# Grails - How to get list of distinct User Objects

Tags: grails

Is there a way that, i can get list of distinct `User` objects(based on username). And still get result as a List of `User` Objects rather than, List of username's.

My code is

```
def criteria = User.createCriteria()
def users = criteria.list() {
    projections {
        distinct("username")
    }
    setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ROOT_ENTITY)
}
return users
```

Currently am getting List of the usernames, not User.

Comment: User.findAll doesn't work?

Comment: @baxxabit 1.) I need to get distinct User objects(based on username). 2.) I have to use criteria, as my actual list is based on a complex search. So findAll() wont fit in.

Comment: `criteria.listDistinct()`?

Comment: As per Grails document "The listDistinct() method does not work well with the pagination options maxResult and firstResult." Also user here, should be distinct based on the username, not based on equals method or id.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense from a database standpoint.  Once you are doing a distinct call you would just be arbitrarily grabbing the first result that matches the username and persisting it back.  You would probably need to use HQL to accomplish this, but I'm still not certain why you would want to.  It seems to me that there is a design flaw in the User table to begin with if usernames can be duplicated.

Answer (score 16):

Ya projection is like filtering and selecting by username you should change it to

```
def criteria = User.createCriteria()
def users = criteria.listDistinct() {
    projections {
        groupProperty("username")
    }
}
return users
```

JOB DONE!

Comment: It should be `groupProperty` camel case :)

Answer (score 4):

One of these should work - I haven't tested any of them, I leave that up to you :)

- `User.list().unique()`
- `User.list().unique()` with the `equals()` method on the `User` domain class overridden to compare objects using the `username`
- `User.list().unique { it.username }` (might need `toArray()` after `list()`)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that, this is in-memory filtering. First all user objects are fetched and then we remove duplicate entries. Not good for a table with millions of entries. And i should be using a "Criteria'. Because my actual search is complex.

Comment: Can you use the `users` list of usernames (as you have in your question) and get objects for those... `def userObjects = users.collect { User.findByUsername(it) }`?

Comment: That would result in two db calls. Not good if performance is of high priority. :)

Comment: Are the usernames repeated often? If the distinct list is only slightly smaller than the number of table entries the in-memory filtering shouldn't be bad...

Comment: The usernames are repeated often, usually more than 70% of the search results are duplicates.

Comment: This is sloppy programming, filtering in-memory

Answer (score 2):

```
def criteria = User.createCriteria()
def users = criteria.list() {
    projections {
        distinct("username")
    }
    setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ROOT_ENTITY)
}
```

Just replace setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ROOT_ENTITY) with resultTransformer(ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP). You will get a list of string as a result

otherwise just replace .list with .listDistinct and use do not need distinct("username"), just can be property("username");

Usually people get problems with pagination. not results. If you already had something like:

```
User.createCriteria().list([max:params.max,offset:params.offset],{
createAlias("others", "others", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);

ilike("others.firstName", "%${query}%");
});
```

It could result in row duplicates. Because .listDistinct() does not support pagination, just add

```
resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

So query will look like this:

```
User.createCriteria().list([max:params.max,offset:params.offset],{
    resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    createAlias("others", "others", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);

    ilike("others.firstName", "%${query}%");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you got a collection (list, array, ...) (I don't know if work with any type of collection, but work in all that i could test). Use `unique{ it.property }`:

Example:

---

```
def users = []
for (def room in rooms) {
    users.addAll(room.users)
}
return users.unique{ it.id }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using where query(Detached criteria):

```
def userListQuery = User.where{
// Your search criteria
}

def userList = userListQuery.list().unique{ it.username }
```

it should result one query for distinct results.

Comment: This would also fetch all User from db and then do a filtering to find unique results.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the distinct user object based on userName

def userInstance = User.list().unique{ it.user_name}

Comment: How is this answer an improvement over [this much older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612771/487033)?

Comment: This is also an example of in-memory filtering as mentioned by ashipj