# How to get a list of distinct records with projections in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Is there a way that I can get a list of distinct Order objects (based on `customerName`) with projections (selected fields only)? 
Assuming only the id would be different, I want to fetch orders having unique `customerName`. Is it possible using projections or any other way?

My code is:

```
def criteria = Order.createCriteria()
def orders = criteria.list() {
    and {
        eq("showAddress", true)
        like("customerName", "%abcdPqrs%")
    }
    projections {
        distinct("customerName")
        property("deliveryAddress")
        property("billingAddress")
        property("")
    }
}
return orders
```

The above code fetches duplicate (`customerName`) records from Order, how can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grails - How to get list of distinct User Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611185/grails-how-to-get-list-of-distinct-user-objects)

Answer (score 2):

If you will see the SQL query generated by GORM, you will find that the distinct will apply on a complete row instead of the customerName. You can enable the logs by putting

```
logSql = true
```

in datasource.groovy.

You can try this

```
def criteria = Order.createCriteria()
def orders = criteria.list() {
and {
    eq("showAddress", true)
    like("customerName", "%abcdPqrs%")
}
projections {
    groupProperty("customerName")
    property("deliveryAddress")
    property("billingAddress")
    property("")
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this, getting error as: SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'MyDb.this_.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? if it's 5.7 You need to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from my.cnf if it's enabled by removing the entry.