# Removing duplicate records from a list

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a Grails domain class which has 3 string fields - name, number, and type.

I want to create a list of records of type green, but I want to ignore any names that have duplicates, although the associated number for each record might be different.

So I am doing

```
List myResults = myDomain.createCriteria().list(){
        eq("type","green")
}
//Remove duplicates
def newResults=myResults.unique( false ){
        it.name
```

}

But this doesn't seem to work as I still have duplicate names in the resulting list. (I suspect it's removing duplicates records where  the name, number, and type are the same?)

Is there a quick and simple way to do this?

Comment: I ought to mention this is Grails 2.5.6   and I am working with a list of about 12,000 records (so the second part of the above is *really* slow!)

Comment: Any of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611185/grails-how-to-get-list-of-distinct-user-objects

Comment: Thanks Tim, sadly not.   I actually think its a bug somewhere as my code works fine for small lists, but I'm handling a list of over 10,000 and that when I see some of the duplicates not being taken out.

Comment: Can you give an example of duplicates that are left? Would be interesting.

Comment: It's tricky, as it's names/telephone numbers.  I'll try to create a dataset that I can share which demonstrates the problem though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you much on Grails, but looking at the link `tim_yates` provided `listDistinct()` seems like a good option to me.

Still, I might be able to help you with Groovy. Personally, I always try to avoid `unique()`. While it's very concise and readable, it's slow and needs roughly `n*(n/2)` comparisons where `n` is the size of the list. For a list with 10.000 elements you need 50.000.000 comparisons. But if `name` is really just a String it should at least work.

I will assume that the order does'nt matter. If the class of `.name` implements a proper `hashCode()` the obvious way would be to exploit that with something like

```
Set newResults = myResults.collectEntries { [it.name, it] }.values()
```

This should run ideally in `O(n)`. Note that among all objects with the same name the last object will remain.

If `.name`  implements `Comparable` you could also use that:

```
TreeSet newResults = new TreeSet({ o1, o2 -> o1.name <=> o2.name })
newResults.addAll(myResults)
```

This runs in `O(n*log(n))` and should also be pretty fast. Note that among all objects with the same name the first object will remain.